# Помощь по ошибкам страниц в ошибках google search console

Tags: seo, индексация, google-search-console, indexerror

Мне нужна помощь по ошибкам страниц в ошибках google search console. Главная проблема в том, что старые ошибки/ссылки не исправляются. Начнём по порядку:

Not found (404): Тут есть много не найденных ссылок и это понятно, но есть ссылки которые были в 404 месяц назад и больше, но они все еще находятся в списке ошибок, не исправились.

Page with redirect: В redirect тоже много неисправных ссылок есть, но половина из них направленны без redirerct, но так же некоторые 404 (в основном старые ссылки, месяц назад)

Crawled - currently not indexed: Незнаю на сколько это является ошибкой, но все же долгое время не идёт индексация страниц и это вводит меня в заблуждение.

Как сделать так чтобы страницы чуть быстрее обновляли SEO содержимое и индексировались?

Заранее благодарю!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По 404 ошибкам - они еще долго будут отображаться, могут месяцами и годами. Если вы исправили url , то отправьте его на переобход. Если удалили навсегда - то сам факт ошибки - это норма.

Для быстрейшего обновления используйте API Гугл консоли и подавайте на переодход (до 200  url в сутки)